# Why does it not detect DB changes(functions)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I'm learning firebase functions and I'm trying to have a function detect a change in the DB but it doesn't. Its suppose to be detect when the gamemode is changed though it doesn't do shit. if it does detect the change it changes it to gamemode 3 though as stated it does not do anything. This is done via firestore

my test DB: https://gyazo.com/91afd83cd27a0e7c55bd79b2b86529bf

Here is what i do to trigger it: 
https://gyazo.com/8c7206d80a343b0e7ee9432cf3fae47c

and my node.js script is as follows:

```
 exports.tellGameModeofUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate(event => {
    // Retrieve the current and previous value
    const data = event.data.data();
    const previousData = event.data.previous.data();

    // We'll only update if the name has changed.
    // This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
    console.log("the new game mode: " + data );
    console.log("old gmae mode: " + previousData)
    if (data.gamemode === previousData.gamemode){
      return;
    }else if (data.gamemode === "1"){
      console.log("value changed game mode on");
    }

});
```

When I check the log is see nothing posted, there is no trigger.

Comment: @PeterHaddad i not sure about either, how can i check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud functions have been updated, so you need to change to the following:

```
exports.tellGameModeofUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onUpdate(event => {
const data = event.data.data();
const previousData = event.data.previous.data();
```

to this:

```
exports.tellGameModeofUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onUpdate((change,context) => {
const data = change.after.data();
const previousData = change.before.data();
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore

Comment: Finally it detects the trigger but  it says this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at 
 exports.tellGameModeofUser.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/user_code/index.js:26:30)

Comment: @jack use capital "U" `Users` since its capital in the database, also change name `data` to `afterData` just to avoid confusion `('Users/{userId}')`

Comment: so I changed the thing you have said the capitalization and the var name. Though its the same error even though there is no var named "data". I changed the name of that var.

Comment: i tried to use ".val();" as done in the doc but it has the same issue

Comment: are you redeploying the function?

Comment: nvm i had to update it and had to change some of the code

Answer (score 0):

So 1 I had to update the firebase to 1.0.0 and that had allowed me to use the new function syntax. Then I was able to use the new syntax for onUpdate functions and have the function run as needed.

```
  exports.tellGameModeofUser = functions.firestore.document('Users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate((change,context) => {

      console.log("Hey");
      console.log("change: " +change);
      const beforeData = change.before.data() // data before the write
      const afterData = change.after.data(); // data after the write

    // We'll only update if the name has changed.
    // This is crucial to prevent infinite loops.
    console.log("the new game mode: " + afterData );
    console.log("old gmae mode: " + beforeData)
    if (afterData.gamemode === beforeData.gamemode){
      console.log("game mode is the same");
      return;
    }else if (afterData.gamemode === "1"){
      console.log("value changed game mode on");
    }

});
```